# How to generate unique Auto increament id field across multiple data centers

Tags: mysql

I have multiple mysql servers deployed in three different data centers. Now my database has few tables with Auto increment id column. I want these columns in all three data center must have unique id across the data centers. Is it possible in Mysql or i need to generate these columns programmatically ?

For example in data center D1 has table T1 with id 1, then data centers D2 and D3 must not generate id 1 for table T1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using replication to 'replicate' data between the different data centers then you can use something like:

auto_increment_increment=3

auto_increment_offset=1 #data center 1

auto_increment_offset=2 #data center 2

auto_increment_offset=3 #data center 3

which will then offset the auto increment accordingly. e.g.

data center1 - 1, 4, 7

data center2 - 2, 5, 8

data center3 - 3, 6, 9